# How do I make sure Docker django site is accessible via url even after extended period of inactivity on server?

Tags: django, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have deployed a Django REST API using Docker on AWS EC2 instance. Due to low traffic on site api sees the extended period of inactivity and it throughs 503 error (Service Unavailable). The aws logs are ok with no signs of throttle. How do I make sure my service is always available without me needing to manually restart the docker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Docker container HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) or docker-compose [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck)